# React native navigation 5 stackNavigator not working on production

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using `ReactNavigation` for tab navigator and `stackNavigator`. It's working 100% on development, mode but the `stacNavigator` is not working on production builds. The app is not crashing, it just isn’t navigating through pages. But the tab navigator is working fine.

Anyone having this issue?

I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8031).

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import AdminHome from './AdminScr/AdminHome
import AdmLogin from './AdminScr/AdminLogin';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
    function App() {
       return (
          <View style={styles.container}  >
             <Stack.Navigator style={{ backgroundColor: '#e91e63' }}>

               <Stack.Screen name="AdmHome" component={AdminHome} options={{
                  title: 'Admin Home',
                  headerStyle: {
                   //backgroundColor: '#1e90ff',
                    backgroundColor: '#E66E2F'
                    },
                  headerTintColor: '#fff',
                  headerTitleStyle: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                 },
                }}
               />

               <Stack.Screen name="AdmLogin" component={AdmLogin} options={{
                     title: 'Admin Login',
                      headerStyle: {
                      backgroundColor: '#E66E2F',
                         },
                     headerTintColor: '#fff',
                    headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                      },
                   }} 
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>

    </View>
  );
}

export default () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <App />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e91e63',

  },
});
```

Calling in **AdminLogin.js** page.

```
//For Arrow Function

   const AdmLogin=(props)=> {   //Passing props in fat area like (props).
           return (
              <View>
                 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signinbutton} onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("AdmHome")}  >
                      <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Sign In</Text>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
          )}

//For Class Method

       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signinbutton} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("AdmHome")}  >
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}> Sign In</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
```